# Excel - count occurrences in row and comma separated cell

Tags: excel, expression

I have a datasheet where I want to count all the occurrences of a word down the column. But the column can contain several words separated by a comma.

```
False Negative
False Negative, False Positive
```

This is an example. The result column can only contain the following expressions:

```
False Negative
False Positive
Positive
```

So I would like a result column consisting of based on the example above:

```
False Negative 2
False Positive 1
```

This way I can make diagrams from the values.

I am not very good at Excel but I know how to input expressions just not how to write the logic.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

I don't want the phrase "False Positive" to count 1 up on "Positive". It needs to look for the comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your example, it appears that you want to count the occurrence of certain phrases in your data, not just words.  If that is the case, and the phrases are non-exclusive, then the following formula might work:

Rng is the range of your column, e.g. $A$1:$A$100
G1 contains the phrase of interest, e.g. False Positive

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEN(Rng)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Rng,G1,"")))/LEN(G1))
```

and fill down as needed.

Note that the above will count 2 for the number of "Positive", since "Positive" is a part of False Positive.  If you want something different, you will need to tell us what you want.

**EDIT**  Since you now indicate that you do **not** want to count False Positive as an instance of Positive, I will provide a User Defined Function which checks to ensure that the phrase in question is comma separated.

To enter this User Defined Function (UDF), **alt-F11** opens the Visual Basic Editor.
Ensure your project is highlighted in the Project Explorer window.
Then, from the top menu, select Insert/Module and
paste the code below into the window that opens.

To use this User Defined Function (UDF), enter a formula like

```
=FindPhrase(Rng,G1)
```

in some cell.

```
Option Explicit
Function FindPhrase(SearchRange As Range, Phrase As String) As Long
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object
    Dim sPat As String
    Dim V As Variant
    Dim I As Long, J As Long

V = SearchRange

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .ignorecase = True
    .Pattern = "(?:^|,\s*)" & Phrase & "(?:\s*,|$)"
End With

For I = 1 To UBound(V, 1)
    If RE.test(V(I, 1)) Then J = J + 1
Next I

FindPhrase = J

End Function
```

**EDIT2**  If there can be more than a single instance of Phrase in each cell, and you want to count them separately, then, in the above, either change

```
.Pattern = "(?:^|,\s*)Positive(?=(?:\s*,|$))"
```

or use the following, different, UDF (which could also be easily adapted to count just a single instance, and may run faster than the first):

```
Option Explicit
Function FindPhrase2(SearchRange As Range, Phrase As String) As Long
    Dim V As Variant
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, K As Long
    Dim aStrings As Variant

V = SearchRange
For I = 1 To UBound(V)
    aStrings = Split(V(I, 1), ",")
        If IsArray(aStrings) Then
            For J = 0 To UBound(aStrings)
                If Trim(aStrings(J)) = Trim(Phrase) Then K = K + 1
            Next J
        Else
            If Trim(aStrings) = Trim(Phrase) Then K = K + 1
        End If
Next I

FindPhrase2 = K

End Function
```

Comment: Hi Ron. I tried your expression but it keeps giving me an error. =SUMPRODUCT((LEN(Rng)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C4:C24,E4,"")))/LEN(E4)) I have put the word False Positive in E4. When I say OK, it marks thie bit C24,E4,""

Comment: I just get the standard excel dialog with "The formula you typed contains an error".. and by the way please look at the updated question. I don't want "False Positive" to count up "Positive".

Comment: Ahhh it's not comma separated arguments that SUBSTITUTE takes... its ; .. the line should read SUBSTITUTE(C4:C24;E4;""). But now I get #NAME? in the field where the expression is.

Comment: I'm not sure, but did you define Rng?

Comment: Yes, some non-US versions of Excel will use the semicolon for an argument separator

Comment: @RonnieJespersen One other question:  Can you have more than one instance in each line?  For example, should Positive, Positive count as one(1) or two(2)?

Comment: My current statement is: =SUMPRODUCT((LEN(Rng)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C4:C24;E4;"")))/LEN(E4)) E4 contains False Positive .. The results will now contain the same expression twice in a row. So Positive wont be there twice in one single row. Ah and I see the problem with Rng ofc... the statement should read =SUMPRODUCT((LEN(C4:C24)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C4:C24;E4;"")))/LEN(E4))

Comment: Ah didn't see your edited answer.. The first piece of code seemed to do the trick. It looks like its counting correctly! :) A lot of work for some simple numbers ;) Accepted and up-voted. Thanks a lot!